# How to get the background color of a website in Flutter mobile

Tags: html, flutter, dart

When displaying websites I'd like to make the status bar color match the color of the website background, but I keep getting empty document styles returned in my function.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:universal_html/parsing.dart';

  Future<String?> _getBackgroundColor(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    String? bodyBackgroundColor;

    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
      final document = parseHtmlDocument(response.body);
      bodyBackgroundColor = document.body?.style.backgroundColor;

      debugPrint(
        bodyBackgroundColor != null
            ? 'Body background color: $bodyBackgroundColor'
            : 'Body background color is null.',
      );
    }

    return bodyBackgroundColor;
  }
```